# How do I select from `|` to `|`?

Tags: regex

How can I select the text from `|` to `|`? For example:

```
I have to select | this part | and not this
```

I tried with `(^|\>|\s)\|(\S+)`, but in this way it selects just the first word.

I have to select all the characters between the first `|` and the second `|`. Do you have any suggestions on how can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you use a programming language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex, and capture the contents from group1

```
\|([^|]*)\|
```

Here, `|` is a meta character hence it needs escaping. You start the pattern by matching a `|` then capture any characters other than `|` zero or more times and capture it in group1 and then further again match a `|` and get your contents from first grouping pattern.

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eXX3TC/1)**

Comment: @J.Luca: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Try `\|(.*?)\|`. The question mark makes this a non-greedy expression.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
\|(.*?[^\|])\|
```

Which can select everything except for a new line and the pipe (which has back slash before it).

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are great if you only have a single pair of `|`, but what if you have multiple instances that you want to match? For example:

```
| one | two | three | four | five |
```

In the example above, there are five possible strings that are between two `|`'s. Any of the answers above will only match `one`, `three` and `five`, and will **not** match `two` or `four`.

At this point you may be wondering: why? The answer is simple: The regex engine can not match the same text twice.

Consider what happens when it matches `| one |`, for example: Because the `|` after `one` has already matched, and it can't be matched again, the remaining text that is available for matching is:

```
 two | three | four | five |
```

Note the lack of a `|` before `two`.  In this remaining text, `two` is clearly not a match, and so the string `| three |` is actually the next match. The same will happen with `four`.

What you need is a way to check for the presence of `|`, but not include it in the match. This can be achieved using **lookaheads** and **lookbehinds**. Now, this will depend on the flavor of regex you're using actually providing these constructs, so you mileage may vary.

This is what a **positive lookbehind** looks like:

```
(?<=insert_expression_here)
```

It will try to match whatever expression you put there, ending the match exactly at the current position in the original expression.

A **positive lookahead** does kind of the opposite:

```
(?=insert_expression_here)
```

It will try to match whatever expression you put there, **starting** the match exactly at the current position in the original expression.

Knowing this, it becomes clear that we must check for `|` at the start and at the end of the match, using both a lookbehind (`(?<=\|)`) at the start, and a lookahead (`(?=\|)`) at the end.

This is what the final expression looks like:

```
(?<=\|).*?(?=\|)
```

[See it live!](https://regex101.com/r/uA60NF/1)

There's no need for a capture: The only text that will match is the text you're interested in. Also, note that we are using a **lazy expression**: basically, instead of trying to match as many characters as possible (the default behavior), which would match the whole string, we want to match as *few* characters as possible. This will ensure that there are no stray `|` characters inside your match.

And here is a great [tutorial](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) if you want to learn more about lookaheads and lookbehinds. Learning about them will not only give you more options when constructing regular expressions, but also give you a better insight on how the regex engine works.